# Can iptables distinguish between the interfaces of a bridge?

Tags: iptables

I have three interfaces in a bridge like this

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports enp0s10 wlx00e032800384 wlx08beac0a6c1d
    address 192.168.1.31
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

An open AP is running on the third interface and for a start I want to block everything except 1 MAC address.
I thought that this would do it (and limit anythig on that inteface to only being able to ssh to the AP box)

```
iptables -A INPUT -i wlx08beac0a6c1d -m mac ! --mac-source 00:30:65:05:9F:4D -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i wlx08beac0a6c1d -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlx08beac0a6c1d -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i wlx08beac0a6c1d -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlx08beac0a6c1d -j DROP
```

But it doesn't.

My guess is that the reason is because `iptables` only sees `br0` and doesn't care about the individual interfaces? Is there a way of doing this?

I guess one way is to put the open AP on a different subnet and then somehow route between the two subnets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with [`physdev`](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbBQ):

> ## physdev
>
> This module matches on the bridge port input and output devices enslaved to a bridge device. This module is a part of the infrastructure that enables a transparent bridging IP firewall and is only useful for kernel versions above version 2.5.44.
>
> [!] --physdev-in *name*
>
> Name of a bridge port via which a packet is received (only for packets entering the **INPUT**, **FORWARD** and **PREROUTING** chains). If the interface name ends in a "+", then any interface which begins with this name will match. If the packet didn't arrive through a bridge device, this packet won't match this option, unless '!' is used.
>
> [!] --physdev-out *name*
>
> Name of a bridge port via which a packet is going to be sent (for bridged packets entering the **FORWARD** and **POSTROUTING** chains). If the interface name ends in a "+", then any interface which begins with this name will match.
>
> [!] --physdev-is-in
>
> Matches if the packet has entered through a bridge interface.
>
> [!] --physdev-is-out
>
> Matches if the packet will leave through a bridge interface.
>
> [!] --physdev-is-bridged
>
> Matches if the packet is being bridged and therefore is not being routed. This is only useful in the FORWARD and POSTROUTING chains.

Comment: Mostly right :)
There seems to be a problem with `physdev-out`; the command `iptables -A OUTPUT -m physdev --physdev-out wlx08beac0a6c1d -j DROP` fails: `iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables):  RULE_APPEND failed (Invalid argument): rule in chain OUTPUT`.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough You can only use `--physdev-out` in `FORWARD` and `POSTROUTING`, not in `OUTPUT`.